# Objective-C uninitialized pointers vs null pointers

Tags: objective-c, pointers, null

Maybe my memory has gone completely wacko, but I think I remember that declaring pointers without initializing them made them point to nil. But recently this doesn't seem to be the case. Has it always been this way? Or has it something to do with the compiler settings?

Comment: Only static "fields" are initialized to `nil`, I think.  Local variables would point to garbage.  I think that has been the case always.  Do you remember any specifics?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instance variables of objects are initialized to `nil` in `alloc` (the whole object is bzeroed).

**Edit:**
Also, global and static storage variables are initialized to zero (6.7.8 10 of the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1336.pdf), thanks Derek for pointing that out).

Local stack variables are not initialized automatically. This did not change in known history.

Comment: Actually, globals and static variables are always initialized.

Comment: Really? The following code runs without assertions, which suggests that they are initialized to `nil` upon declaration, but become non-nil when alloc is called:

        `NSString* foo;  
        assert(foo==nil);
        foo = [NSString alloc];
        assert(foo!=nil);
        foo = [foo init];
        assert(foo!=nil);`

Comment: Aha - I've realised you mean instance variables are init'd to `nil` when the _object_ that they are members of is `alloc`'d

Answer (score 7):

From [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html):

> ### Stack Variables Are Initialized with `nil`
>
> Using ARC, strong, weak, and autoreleasing stack variables are now implicitly initialized with `nil`. For example:
>
> ```
> - (void)myMethod {
>     NSString *name;
>     NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
> }
> ```
>
> will log `null` for the value of name rather than perhaps crashing.